# How to multiply a single number by a mixed format column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table, and I wish to multiply column a by column b, a is always a single number and b column may sometimes be a vector:

```
library(data.table)
tt <- c(33,44)
dt <- data.table(a=list(1,2,3)
                 , b = list(11,22,tt))

dt[, t2 := sapply(b, function(x) x*a)]
```

I get an error: `Error in x * a : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Because a is always a single number, I expected that row 3 would work, even though b is a vector.

The solution I found is to use mapply:

```
dt[, t2 := mapply(function(x,y) x*y, a, b)]
```

Why it does not work with sapply/lapply?

Comment: Both 'a' and 'b' are list.  You want to multiply by corresponding elements of the list columns.  So, either `Map` or `mapply` can be used.  `sapply` you are looping over a single column and multiplying by the entire list of 'a' with each element of 'b'.  In the first one, you are doing `3 * list(1:3)
Error in 3 * list(1:3) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Ditto ... to be clear, `dt[, t2 := Map(\`*\`, a, b)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `dt$a[[1]] * dt$b` work? (No.) While the first argument is a vector of length 1, the second is not a vector, it is a `list`, and `list`s don't do arithmetic. `sapply` only iterates over one list/vector of values, so while `sapply(a, function(AA) AA * b)` might seem like a good start, `b` still reflects a `list` so cannot be done.

What you are trying to do is multiply `a[[1]]` with `b[[1]]`, then `a[[2]]` with `b[[2]]`, etc. That is what `Map` and `mapply` do well.

Some things about how they relate.

```r
## equivalent
lapply(lst1, function(z) z + 1)
Map(function(z) z + 1, lst1)

## equivalent
sapply(lst1, function(z) z + 1)
mapply(function(z) z + 1, lst1)
```

That's it for single-vector processing. But when you want to iterate over multiple (two *or more*) vectors/lists at the same time, "zipping" them together, there are two options:

```r
stopifnot(length(lst1) == length(lst2))

## equivalent
sapply(seq_along(lst1), function(ind) {
  lst1[[ind]] * lst2[[ind]]
})
mapply(function(o1, o2) o1 * o2, lst1, lst2)
mapply(`*`, lst1, lst2)
```

Commonalities and differences to know about them:

- `sapply` and `mapply` will try to simplify the return value if possible, so they might return a `vector` (if the return value is 1), a `matrix` (if the return value is a vector), or a `list` (if any length is different from the others). You can *force* a `list` with `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` and `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)` (case difference is important).
- `lapply` and `Map` *always* return `list`s, regardless of the above conditions; many find this output consistency more reliable/desirable in a programmatic sense (i.e., in functions/packages).
- `lapply` will only return a named `list` if the vector/list is named, otherwise it is only indexable positionally; all of the others will auto-name the returned `list` if the input is named or if the input is `character`. (There might be more rules/exceptions to this, but it's a start.)